# How to insert a picture/text label at specific coordinates in a word 2007 document using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ms-word, office-interop, css-position

I can do this to insert picture and text at a default location:

```
        private static object objTrue = true;
        private static object objFalse = false;
        private static object objMissing = Missing.Value;
        private static object objEndOfDoc = @"\endofdoc"; // \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark.

        ...

        this.WordApp = new Word.Application();
        this.WordDoc = new Word.Document();
        this.WordApp.Visible = true;
        this.WordDoc = this.WordApp.Documents.Add(ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);

        this.WordDoc.Content.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
        FileName: @"C:\MyLogo.png",
        LinkToFile: ref objMissing,
        SaveWithDocument: ref objTrue,
        Range: objMissing);

        // Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
        var paragraph1 = this.WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref objMissing);
        paragraph1.Range.Text = "Heading 1";
        paragraph1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        paragraph1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;    //24 pt spacing after paragraph.
        paragraph1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

How can I move it to any location I want? When I am creating PowerPoint (manually), I can position stuff anywhere. When I manually insert a shape, I can position it anywhere. How can I achieve similar result when inserting pictures and text labels programmatically using c#? I have not had success figuring this out using Google searches.

Answer (score 6):

The `Range` class is used in word to determine where almost everything goes in a document.  If you replaced the `Range` parameter in `this.WordDoc.Content.InlineShapes.AddPicture` with a valid `Range` object, it would insert the picture at that place in the word document, and the same goes for paragraphs.

According to MSDN for the AddPicture method on InlineShapes:

> Range: Optional Object. The location where the picture will be placed in the text. If the range isn't collapsed, the picture replaces the range; otherwise, the picture is inserted. If this argument is omitted, the picture is placed automatically.

Another way would be to use the `Shapes` member of the document instead of `InlineShapes`.  The `AddPicture` method on the `Shapes` class allows you to specify the coordinates:

```
this.WordDoc.Content.Shapes.AddPicture(
    [In] string FileName, 
    [In, Optional] ref object LinkToFile, 
    [In, Optional] ref object SaveWithDocument, 
    [In, Optional] ref object Left, 
    [In, Optional] ref object Top, 
    [In, Optional] ref object Width, 
    [In, Optional] ref object Height, 
    [In, Optional] ref object Anchor
);
```

[InlineShapes.AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture(v=office.14).aspx)

[Shapes.AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addpicture(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Cool, it works! How can I programmatically continue the normal flow after this by skipping the first say 2 inches from the top? I can manually hit Shift-Enter (but not Enter) about 6-7 times and continue to type stuff up as normal. Currently I am replacing the inserted picture with new stuff that I am adding later.

Comment: how to add a bookmark in a rang? `Range oRange =??
                oRange.Document.Bookmarks.Add("bsmText", ref objMissing);`